# Deploying a service on Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I have a util method that deploys a service on Ignite:

```
private static void startNewService(String queryId, String sqlQuery, long timeInterval) {
    QueryServiceImpl cepService = new QueryServiceImpl(queryId, sqlQuery, timeInterval);

    ServiceConfiguration cfg = new ServiceConfiguration();
    cfg.setService(cepService);
    cfg.setName(queryId);
    cfg.setTotalCount(1);
    cfg.setMaxPerNodeCount(1);

    System.out.println("---- Deploying the service. "+queryId);
    services.deploy(cfg);
    System.out.println("---- Deployed the service. "+queryId);
}
```

When I run this from my client machine, I get the following error in the server machines:

```
[12:13:26,640][SEVERE][srvc-deploy-#35%myGrid%][GridServiceProcessor] Failed to initialize service (service will not be deployed): Query1
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: com.demo.ignite.service.QueryServiceImpl
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9739)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor.copyAndInject(GridServiceProcessor.java:1206)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor.redeploy(GridServiceProcessor.java:1127)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.GridServiceProcessor.processAssignment(GridServiceProcessor.java:1750)
   ......
 Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: com.demo.ignite.service.QueryServiceImpl
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:695)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1755)
    ....
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.ignite.service.QueryServiceImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    .... 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8465)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:347)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:686)
```

My QueryServiceImpl implements Service, QueryService where QueryService is an interface with a method runContinuousQuery().

Please note that I have not manually copied this jar/class to the server classpath. I am expecting ignite to load the required classes to the Ignite server nodes and run the service there. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently peer deployment is not supported for services, so your service should be on the classpath for every node. You can find a note about it in the documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-grid

Comment: How does one develop a service if every change requires a deployment? I had the same problem even using a local Ignite server.